# Laravel5.5: save Provider data in session to avoid overload

Tags: laravel, memory-efficient

I have made a ServiceProvider to load data on several views. Like this:

```
View::composer(['components.navigation.main.search','search.*','page-parts.cats','page-parts.categories_menu','page-parts.categories_more','page-parts.cats_top','components.modals.off-category'],function ($view) {
            $view->with([
                'toplevel_categories' => Category::topLevel()->orderBy('name')->get(),
            ]);
        });
```

But on several html pages he needs to load multiple of these views and I don't want to load the topLevel categories each time to avoid overload and less runtime.

Can I store the loaded data (toplevel_categories) in a session or what is the most efficient way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply cache the variable and use it in the callback like:

```
$topLevelCategories = Category::topLevel()->orderBy('name')->get();

View::composer([], function($view) use ($topLevelCategories) {
    $view->with([
        'toplevel_categories' => $topLevelCategories
}
```

You could even use the cache mechanic from laravel itself to save an additional query, like caching it for 30 minutes (assuming the database hasnt changed in the meantime):

```
// Save the categories in the cache or retrieve them from it.
$topLevelCategories = Cache::remember('topLevelCategories', 30, function() {
    return Category::topLevel()->orderBy('name')->get();
});
```

Note that for Laravel 5.8 the second parameter is in SECONDS, for 5.7 and below it is in MINUTES.

Since your service provider is only loaded once per request/lifecycle this should do the trick.

Comment: Yup. You want to cache the query and use the results in your view composer.

Comment: Thank you! should I add an exception when the 30 min cache is expired?

Comment: when it expires it calls the callback function :) so the `remember()` function just makes sure that after 30 minutes, it is retrieved using the callback function and saved to the cache again. If you would place a `die('die here')` in the callback function it would only die the moment it is about to be written to the cache. The other 1000 calls to the function will result in returning the value from the cache.